# How to calculate pairwise cosine distance of matrix using broadcasting in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix like this where each row is a vector and need to calculate pairwise cosine distance between the vectors (in this example, as a 2x2 matrix) without using loops? I understand for cartesian distance one can pad up a dimension but don't know the best method here.

```
m = np.array([[1, 3, 5],[2,6,10]])
```

Comment: Why aren't you allowed to use loops? This seems like an arbitrary step that really limits your progress.

Comment: @RoboMop Looping is prohibited to ensure that students understand the implicit iteration of numpy's broadcasting functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This type of question will get you berated with "Stack isn't for homework" but I guess you could just do this...

```
from numpy import linalg as LA
import numpy as np
m = np.array([[1, 3, 5],[2,6,10]])
cos = float(sum(m[0]*m[1]))/float(LA.norm(m[0])*LA.norm(m[1]))
```

of course if you wanted to avoid using `linlag`

```
float(sum(m[0]*m[1]))/(float(sum(m[0]*m[0]))**0.5*float(sum(m[1]*m[1]))**0.5)
```

See link -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity

Comment: Thanks, but I should have specified that I was looking for a generic solution of avoiding loops not assuming it's 2 vectors only

Comment: I don't know how to do pairwise combinations without a loop sorry. Like you could use `ittertools` and `map` or you could accommodate the calculation within a class but I think that's beyond the point here as you would still need a loop to generate the resulting pairwise matrix.